# $(\epsilon,N)$ proof that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3-3n^2+4n-7}{2n^3-10n^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that: for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n \geq N$ 
$$\left|\frac{n^3-3n^2+4n-7}{2n^3-10n^2+1} - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \epsilon.$$

After some manipulation I have 
$$\left|\frac{4n^2+8n-15}{4n^3-20n^2+2}\right| < \epsilon.$$

I'm stuck here. I think I should find some other ratio of polynomials which is simpler and greater than $\displaystyle{\left|\frac{4n^2+8n-15}{4n^3-20n^2+2}\right|}$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For large enough $N$ (say $N = 10$), 
$$4n^2+8n-15 < 8n^2$$
$$4n^3-20n^2+2 > 2n^3$$
So that the ratio is smaller than $4/n$.